# Uploading Images through Sinatra

Tags: ruby, image, sinatra

I'm using the example code from this page:
http://www.wooptoot.com/file-upload-with-sinatra

When I try to upload an image file (png or jpg), it uploads successfully and I can see the file in the proper directory, but it gets corrupted in the process. I cannot open the image. Doing a diff with the original files, I see several newlines that are missing in the uploaded version.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3p392 on Windows.

Edit:
I tried a test outside the context of Sinatra

```
File.open('57-new.jpg', "wb") do |f|
  f.write(File.open('57.jpg', 'rb').read)
end
```

That works. The only difference is the addition of the binary flags. When using Sinatra I can set the binary flag on the write operation, but I'm not sure how I can set it on the read since I seem to be passed a file object by the request.

```
File.open('uploads/' + params['myfile'][:filename], "wb") do |f|
  f.write(params['myfile'][:tempfile].read)
end
```

Comment: I seriously doubt the file is corrupted by the Ruby `File` class.

Comment: I'm open to any explanations. I just stated what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like all I needed was the binary flag when opening the new file.

```
File.open('uploads/' + params['myfile'][:filename], "wb") do |f|
  f.write(params['myfile'][:tempfile].read)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering it in the end Anthony. Saved me big time!